# How to separate getters and setters from managed bean in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans, getter-setter

I am developing a login page in JSF. I have two attributes email and password. I want to have two java classes. One for setters and getters, two for logic. So, how to separate setters and getters from managed bean. My code is

```
private String email;
private String password;
private String message;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public void login()
{
 //logic
}
```

I want to have login() method in one class and setters and getters in another class. And also how to Use .xhtml for both files. please help me

Comment: Just push those getters and/or setters to the bottom of the class - the managed bean and do not show any interest in them. They are then onwards no longer messy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Keep the data in DTO class and create object and setters getters in Bean class. and access the properties of DTO class through Bean class in xhtml.

Bean class

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean")
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

LoginDTO loginDTO = new LoginDTO();

public String logIn() {
   //here the logic
}

public LoginDTO getLoginDTO() {
    return loginDTO;
}

public void setLoginDTO(LoginDTO loginData) {
    this.loginDTO = loginData;
}
```

}

DTO class

```
public class LoginDTO {
private String email;
private String password;
private String message;
private String localeCode;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

}
```

and access data in xhtml like  value="#{loginBean.loginDTO.email}"

Answer (score 1):

> how to seperate getters and setters from managed bean in JSF?

Just introduce another managed bean whose purpose it is to hold your data.

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class LoginModel implements Serializable {
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    //Getters and setters ...
}

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private LoginModel loginData;

    public String logIn(){
        if(isLoginDataValid(loginData)){
            return "index.xhtml";
        }
    }
}
```

Please make sure you use `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` as the annotation. Do not use `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`.

Using part of jsf might look like.

```
<h:form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td>
                <h:inputText value="#{loginModel.userName}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>
                <h:inputText value="#{loginModel.password}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginController.logIn}"/>          
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</h:form>
```

Comment: injected object(model) getting nullpointer exception when login.

Comment: Please make sure you use javax.faces.view.ViewScoped as the annotation. Do not use javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped.

Comment: javax.faces.view.ViewScoped is not available for me. Am i need to add any jar file? please help me you can solve my problem.

Comment: If you use maven add the javaee-api as a dependency with scope 'provieded'. If you use Java EE 7 http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0. If not you can download it from the same link and add it to the classpath.

Comment: But how you added javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped into your classpath?

Comment: No I am using maven, So I have added dependency, which you have told. But even now, it is getting null pointer exception when executing #{loginModel.userName}.

Comment: Your JSF backing beans are annotated with javax.inject.Named and javax.faces.view.ViewScoped? You also inject them with javax.inject.Inject annotation? Do you use a Java EE application server?

Comment: I have written as it is, whatever you told. But getting error  like -               value="#{loginModel.userName}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginModel' resolved to null: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @12,62 value="#{loginModel.userName}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginModel' resolved to null

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a solution for separating the getters and setters into a different class. For what I think you would just run in circles getting effectly the same semantic result as having the getters and setters on the same bean as the rest of your stuff.

Now, for your business logic, you could always use different classes to manage that logic. Nothing is really stopping your from doing that, as long as you reference them through your bean methods, as this bean is your gate to your JSF page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read about [three-tier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture). You should always separate your business logic from presentation tier. In your case presentation tier includes jsf pages and managed beans as controllers. I propose the following template for your application:

1. Create service class `LoginService` and annotate it `@Stateless`:

   ```
   @Stateless
   public class LoginService {
       public void login() {
           //your logic here
       }
   }
   ```
2. Inject this EJB to your managed bean:

   ```
   @EJB private LoginService loginService;

   //getters and setters are omitted
   public void login() {
       loginService.login();
   }
   ```

The template above will separate your business logic from managed bean and hold it frontend-independent (for example, if you decide to add [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) [services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) to your application, you can use EJB injection by the same way). And don't remove getters and setters from your managed bean. Managed bean needs to be a [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) with getters and setters for every field.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about verbosity, you could try the [lombok framework](http://projectlombok.org/) and annotate your fields so getters and setters are not needed

Disclaimer: I did not use it myself

Comment: You can use the lombok.Very useful.I used the lombok framework in my recent project.It reduced boilerplate code.